# Create playlist by youtube data API (python)

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to create a python project to manage your playlist, but I'm having truble creating a new playlist, my code below:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import googleapiclient.discovery


scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]


client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"


# Get credentials and create an API client
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)


request = youtube.playlists().insert(
    part="snippet",
    body={
        "snippet": {
            "title": "new playlist",
        }
    }
)

response = request.execute()
```

The Error:

**googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Unauthorized". Details: "[{'message': 'Unauthorized', 'domain': 'youtube.header', 'reason': 'youtubeSignupRequired', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}]">**

I think it's because I didn't have the API key, but it still occurs anyways.

Can someone help me @_@

Comment: I think it's because you need to be logged in. Can you try again while being logged in?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I'm logged in the whole time, and the authorize page works normal, the error occurs after the autherization, it may sounds weird but that's what I'm having problem with.

Comment: it would be possible to modify your code as shown [here, in the documentation?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert?hl=es#python) - one key I saw is: `youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
  http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))` - You mentioned you're logged, but, maybe additional code is needed. Sorry for not be more helpful.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thanks for your suggestion, I appritiate your help.
I already figure it out myself, the error occurs because I use the wrong google account
(organization account), I recreate a project with a normal account and it works. Still appritiate your help.  : )

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Please post your answer - see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, the error occurs because I used the organization account from google to create my project’s OAuth Authorization, which is not available for create a new playlist, so I create another project with a normal Google account, and it works perfectly normal.